# Zariski's article on cohomology in algebraic variety

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

Zariski is supposed to have written an article on cohomology in algebraic geometry. It is supposed to be very good and cited as such for instance [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/learn-and-relearn-your-field/#comment-36823). Can anyone supply a precise reference to this? I couldn't find such an article by search for author Zariski in AMS journals. Perhaps it is part of some volume and does not appear in straight search results.

Comment: Dear Doldrums, I just noticed this, and wanted to say that I'm glad to see this article of Zariski's is being read.  Cheers,

Comment: @MattE : Dear Matt E., Thanks for the positive comment; but I am afraid I haven't yet got around to reading it; but I certainly will(unfortunately I am an amateur now and my time for math is like a Cantor set, fortunately one of nonzero, even if small, measure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search problem is likely that Zariski was only one of the authors. Here's the full reference:

> Martin, W. T.; Chern, S. S.; Zariski, Oscar
>
> Scientific report on the Second Summer Institute, several complex variables.
>
> *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* **62** (1956), 79–141.

The full text is even available online: I don't think subscription is required, but I can't tell from here. Link:

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1956-62-02/S0002-9904-1956-10018-9/

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed available without subscription.

Comment: No problem! I am glad the AMS has a sensible access policy about old articles.

Comment: Mo haois Breise.

Comment: Tá brón orm @Doldrums a chara, ach níl me in ann do theachtaireacht a thuiscint ar chor ar bith...

Comment: Oh I see @Doldrums, it was _your_ bounty. Now everything makes sense! For some reason I was convinced it came from another user. Anyway, go raibh míle maith agat!

Comment: No, no, it came from the other guy himself. I was just trying to teach myself Irish! Actually I wanted to say, "Your extra century"; somehow it became "my extra hundred".

Comment: Alright, now everything _really_ makes sense. I was a little confused because _aois_ only means "century" in the sense of time; a hundred of something (like reputation points) would be _céad_. Anyway, maith thú -- lean leis an nGaeilge!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, looking back. The usage of "century" was borrowed from the game of Cricket, which is understandably not traditionally Gaelic. The moral of the story is not to play with stuff I don't know very well!